# onclick event not triggering in IIS 10

Tags: javascript, php, iis, onclick

I have deployed a php+javascript site on a IIS Version 10 (Windows 10). The same code works perfectly fine in IIS 6.1 (Windows 7) but for some reason a javascript function triggered by an onclick event seems not be executed in Win 10.
Please check code below

```
<tr>

              <td><a href="#" onclick="atSubmit(<?php echo $oatt_id ?>);"><img border="0" alt="Attack Update template" title="Attack Update template" src="./img/document_16.png"></a></td>

</tr>

...

<script type="text/javascript">

        function atSubmit(att){
            document.getElementById('atupd').attack_id.value = att;
            document.getElementById('atupd').submit();
        }

</script>
```

The function should set a variable that is subsequently passed via POST to the same page but what happens is that the variable ends up not being set, hence the execution cannot succesfully continue.

What am I missing?

Comment: At a guess, it sounds like in your IIS 10 configuration, you don't have PHP enabled  and configured to handle the file the code you've shown is in. If you look in the web console, I bet you'll find an error when you click that link because the `<?php ...?>` part hasn't been handled server-side: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

Comment: what is " document.getElementById('atupd').attack_id " ?  (not really a good JS code ?)